# "The type Long is not visible" in Eclipse with JDK Compliance 9 and 10

Tags: java, eclipse

With the code provided below, I get the Eclipse error while typing 'The type Long is not visible' (with no further information) on `o.get()`.

I have the latest JDK installed (Java "11.0.1" 2018-10-16, and using in Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0)), and the error only happens when I have the project JDK compliance set to 9 or 10. It does not happen when JDK compliance is set to 1.8 or lower.

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class TestLongNotVisible {

    Optional<Long> o;

    void a() {
        long x = o.get();
    }

}
```

I am looking for a fix for this issue. If anyone has experience with this issue or knows the most likely cause, thank you in advance!

Comment: Works fine with Java-SE 9 compliance level for me. Please update with exact configuration and error screen if possible

Comment: As an aside note that there is an `OptionalLong` class for storing primitive `long` values rather than `Long` objects.

Comment: @nullpointer I found that Lombok is the problem. I am a very big fan of Lombok to say the least, and had updated to a new Java and Eclipse version without properly checking compatibility. Thank you for your comment! Checking the exact configuration helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My projects are set up as Maven projects with a number of dependencies by default. The Lombok dependency causes this problem to happen, since it injects code before compilation. Without the Lombok dependency, everything works as intended. The problem occurs for any project with Lombok as dependency, even when no Lombok features are used.

Lombok does NOT support JDK 10 or higher yet.

If you are having this problem, or a similar problem with errors that should be impossible (such as the type Long not being visible) check your setup for possible code injectors such as Lombok being incompatible with the compiler.